# Как остановить playsound?

Tags: python, аудио, playsound

С помощью playsound в python проигрываю саундтрек, но хочу останавливать его в нужный мне момент. Как это сделать? На английской версии StackOverflow видел решение через multiprocessing, но могу ли я это сделать в самой библиотеке playsound? Есть ли другие способы в нужный момент останавливать проигрывание музыки?

Answer (score 0):

Короче, я начал рыться в библиотеке playsound и обнаружил ссыль на человека, которым вдохновлялся автор этой библиотеки. https://github.com/michaelgundlach/mp3play Там есть множество полезных функций, таких как stop и pause/unpause. Устанавливаете в свою папку с проектом и оттуда импортируете то, что нужно. В проекте на гите даже есть пример, как этим правильно пользоваться.